# Using bcp.exe to successfully import data, even if the column order in the format file differs to that of the table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, bcp

I've been creating a system for my team which allows us to automatically generate large amounts of test data so that we can return our database to a consistent state when we need it.  This needs to be fully automated, but I currently have one issue that's preventing that from happening.

Our database is created using Entity Framework, and we're also using migrations.  The problem is that, as column orders can change because of a migration, it means test data that was exported prior to a migration may no longer import correctly when using bcp.

To illustrate this more clearly, here are the steps to reproduce the behaviour:

Create a simple table:

[image: dbo.Person - original column order]

Create the format file:

> C:\bcp [BCPTest].[dbo].[Person] format nul -f person.xml -x -N -T -S .\SQLExpress

Create the binary output file:

> C:\bcp [BCPTest].[dbo].[Person] out person.dat -N -T -S .\SQLExpress

Reorder the columns and save:

[image: dbo.Person - migration order]

Try to import:

> C:\bcp [BCPTest].[dbo].[Person] in person.dat -f person.xml -N -T -S .\SQLExpress

This will lead to lots of different errors.  This can currently be fixed, by reordering the columns in the tables that failed, manually, saving and rerunning the import, but, as I said earlier, this needs to be fully automated.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `-N` option from the `BCP in` command.  The -N option effectively overrides the format file field ordinals.  The format file specifies the native field formats anyway so the `-N` specification is redundant.

**EDIT:**

Below is an T-SQL example that changes the column mapping order of the original format file xml to match the current table.  This can be extended to handle dropped columns and detections of conditions that must be handled manually, like new not-NULL columns.

I suggest you invoke this from a Powershell script that iterates over your list of format files and calls the proc passing in the original format XML and table name for each.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_GetNewFormatFileXml
      @TableName nvarchar(261)
    , @OriginalFormatFileXml xml
    , @NewFormatFileXml xml OUTPUT
AS

DECLARE @NewFormatFileColumns xml;

--genrate new field/column mappings based in current column ordinal
WITH
    XMLNAMESPACES (
          'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi
        ,  DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format'
        )
SELECT @NewFormatFileColumns = (
    SELECT
          RecordField.ID AS [@SOURCE]
        , NewTableColumn.Name AS [@NAME]
        , OldTableColumn.type AS [@xsi:type]
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            Field.value('@ID', 'int') AS ID
        FROM @OriginalFormatFileXml.nodes('/BCPFORMAT/RECORD/FIELD') AS Record(Field)) AS RecordField
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
              TableColumn.value('@SOURCE', 'int') AS FieldId
            , TableColumn.value('@NAME', 'sysname') AS Name
            , TableColumn.value('@xsi:type', 'sysname') AS type
        FROM @OriginalFormatFileXml.nodes('/BCPFORMAT/ROW/COLUMN') AS TableRow(TableColumn)) AS OldTableColumn ON
        OldTableColumn.FieldId = RecordField.ID
    JOIN (
        SELECT
              Name
            , column_id
        FROM sys.columns
        WHERE 
            object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
        ) AS NewTableColumn ON
            NewTableColumn.Name = OldTableColumn.Name
    ORDER BY NewTableColumn.column_id
FOR XML PATH('COLUMN'), ROOT('ROW'), TYPE);

SET @NewFormatFileXml = @OriginalFormatFileXml;

--remove old column mapping
SET @NewFormatFileXml.modify('
    declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format";
    delete
        (/BCPFORMAT/ROW[1] )[1] 
        ') ;

--add new column mapping
SET @NewFormatFileXml.modify('
    declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format";
    insert sql:variable("@NewFormatFileColumns")
        into (/BCPFORMAT )[1] 
        ') ;
GO

--example usage
DECLARE
    @TableName nvarchar(261) = 'dbo.Person'
    , @OriginalFormatFileXml xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>'
    , @NewFormatFileXml xml;

EXEC dbo.usp_GetNewFormatFileXml
      @TableName = @TableName
    , @OriginalFormatFileXml = @OriginalFormatFileXml
    , @NewFormatFileXml = @NewFormatFileXml OUTPUT;

SELECT @NewFormatFileXml;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, unfortunately, that doesn't work and still generates the same sort of column errors we're seeing now.  In the simplistic case of the example table above, this would result in the following error for each column: `Invalid character value for cast specification`.

Comment: @JohnH, the format file will need also need to be modified if the target tables have a different schema.  Would a solution that modifies the format files to handle the column resequence suffice?  Note there will be cases where this cannot be fully automated, such as adding a new column that does not allow nulls.

Comment: I'm open to all suggestions at the moment, Dan.  Partial automation would still be better than none at all.  I did actually wonder if it was possible to compare the column order of a generated table, programmatically, to that of a format file, and adjust as necessary.

Comment: @JohnH, I edited my answer to add the T-SQL part of a solution.  This can be invoked from a Powershell script after the new database schema is installed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Dan.  I'm not at work at the moment, and it's a national holiday tomorrow, so I'll try this out on Tuesday and get back to you.  Either way, thanks for taking the time to give me such a detailed response; I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  This is definitely an improvement on what we currently have, so thanks for the time you put into it.